# Spend some time to do

Tags: verb-pattern

> 1. He spent all the time he should spend studying to play games
> 2. He spent all the time he should spend studying **playing** games

Which one do you think is correct? Theoretically, (2)，but is it not right for two "ing"s to appear in the adjacent positions?

Comment: There's no rule that says you can't have two "-ing"s in adjacent positions. Where did you hear that?

Comment: @gotube    I haven't seen two "ing"s  occupying adjacent positions,  so I feared there might be a rule  preventing that happening.

Comment: No such rule. The two "-ing" forms are natural together in that sentence. As others have pointed out, the tense of "spend" is incorrect, but that's not what your question is about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is definitely wrong.

There is no rule against using two words ending in *-ing* together, but if you don't like it for stylistic reasons, you could say

> He spent all the time he should have spent in study in playing games.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd use the past participle here:

> He spent all the time he should **have spent** studying playing games.

As for the end of the sentence, either "to play" or "playing" would be correct, but they result in a very clunky sentence. It might be a little clearer if you reorder it:

> All the time he should have spent studying, he spent playing games.